# How to plot pcolor over image matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot some fake data for pcolor over a png image with matplotlib.

In this code I am just drawing an arrow (I'm new to matplotlib):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
im = plt.imread('pitch.png')
implot = plt.imshow(im)


plt.annotate("",
        xy=(458, 412.2), xycoords='data',
        xytext=(452.8, 363.53), textcoords='data',
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-",
                        connectionstyle="arc3"), 
        )

pylab.savefig('foo.png')
```

I just can't plot with pcolor over my png. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create an `Axes` instance (for example with `fig,ax=plt.subplots()`), you can easily plot the `pcolor` on there. Make sure you make the pcolor transparent, so that you can see the `imshow` image underneath.

Here's an example, using the image from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = plt.imread('stinkbug.png')

# Create Figure and Axes objects
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# display the image on the Axes
implot = ax.imshow(im)

# Some dummy data to use in pcolor
x = np.arange(im.shape[1])
y = np.arange(im.shape[0])
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
data = X+Y

# plot the pcolor on the Axes. Use alpha to set the transparency
p=ax.pcolor(X,Y,data,alpha=0.5,cmap='viridis')

# Note I changed your coordinates so the arrow would fit on this image
ax.annotate("",
        xy=(458, 150), xycoords='data',
        xytext=(452.8, 250), textcoords='data',
        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-",
                        connectionstyle="arc3"), 
        )

# Add a colorbar for the pcolor field
fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)

plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

[image]